# error; expected expression before 'else'

Tags: c

I am trying to have the following program to run.. but it keeps on giving me errors at the end..it seems that I forget to close a loop or so.. if someone is able to help me out that would be great!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main () {

//variables
int user_selection, count_donate=0, count_invest=0;
float balance_of_fund, donate_amt, invest_amt;

//input
printf("Welcome!\n");
printf("What is the initial balance of the fund?\n");
scanf("%f", balance_of_fund);

//provide user with options
printf("What would you like to do?\n 1 - Make a donation\n 2 - Make an investment\n 3 -        
Print balance of fund\n 4 - Quit\n");


//work with user selectiom
scanf ("%d", user_selection);

if (user_selection > 0 && user_selection < 4) {

        //ask for donation amount
        for (user_selection = 1; user_selection<=1; user_selection++) {
                    printf("How much would you like to donate?\n");
                    scanf("%f", donate_amt);
                    balance_of_fund = balance_of_fund + donate_amt;
                    count_donate++;
        }

        //ask for investment amount
        for (user_selection = 2; user_selection<=2; user_selection++) {
                    printf("How much would you like to invest?\n");
                    scanf ("%f", invest_amt);
                    balance_of_fund = balance_of_fund - invest_amt;
                    count_invest++;
        }

        //print out final balance for selection 3
        for (user_selection = 3; user_selection<=3; user_selection++) {
                    printf("The final balance is $%.2f.", balance_of_fund);
        printf("There were %d donations and %d investments.",count_donate,             count_invest);
        }

        //Quit for selection 4
        else if (user_selection = 4) {
                    printf("The final balance is $%.2f." ,balance_of_fund);
        }

else    {
        printf("Please make a valid selection");
    }
 return 0;
```

if you have any suggestions please let me know.. at this point I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: This isn't valid C++ anyway. It needs `int main`. And I think what you're looking for is a switch.

Comment: Why are you using for-loops rather than simple if-statements (and yes, a switch would be even better)?

Comment: the reason why im using a for-loops is because it was specifically requested in this assigment.

Comment: and yes it includes int main (somehow it didnt copy it to the screen)

Answer (score 2):

Your first `else` has no `if` for it. This one

```
    //Quit for selection 4
    else if (user_selection = 4) {
```

Also, as @Yu Hao noted in the comments, equality comparison operator in C++ is `==`, not `=`.

The idea behind the preceding `for` cycles also escapes me. Do you actually understand what `for` statement does? I strongly suspect that you don't.

If you add a `}` before that `else`, it should properly balance `if`'s and `else`'s in your code, but it still won't make those `for`'s do anything meaningful.

Comment: Also `=` should be `==`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of the code you have provided:

```
if (...) {
    for (...) {
        ...
    }
    // there is no if preceding else on the next line
    else if (...) {
        ...
    }
// missing }, scope of the first if is not closed properly
else {
    ...
}
```

Also this line:

```
for (user_selection = 1; user_selection<=1; user_selection++) {
```

makes the loop completely useless, i.e. it is the same like there would be no loop, just another scope:

```
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing brace "}" for the if just before the else if and the "Quit for selection 4" comment.

Answer (score 0):

use `switch` case instead for user selection

```
switch(user_selection)
{
 case 1:
 //do something i.e. make donation
 case 2:
 //do something
 .
 .
 .
 default:
}
```

**EDIT**: Try the following code. The only thing I have added is a `}` which you missed and '&' sign before `%d` and `%f`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main ()
{
        //variables
        int user_selection, count_donate=0, count_invest=0;
        float balance_of_fund, donate_amt, invest_amt;

        //input
        printf("Welcome!\n");
        printf("What is the initial balance of the fund?\n");
        scanf("%f",&balance_of_fund);

        //provide user with options
        printf("What would you like to do?\n 1 - Make a donation\n 2 - Make an investment\n 3 -Print balance of fund\n 4 - Quit\n");


        //work with user selectiom
        scanf ("%d",&user_selection);

        if (user_selection > 0 && user_selection < 4)
        {

                    //ask for donation amount
                    for (user_selection = 1; user_selection<=1; user_selection++)
                    {
                                printf("How much would you like to donate?\n");
                                scanf("%f",&donate_amt);
                                balance_of_fund = balance_of_fund + donate_amt;
                                count_donate++;
                    }

                //ask for investment amount
                    for(user_selection = 2; user_selection<=2; user_selection++)
                    {
                                printf("How much would you like to invest?\n");
                                scanf ("%f",&invest_amt);
                                balance_of_fund = balance_of_fund - invest_amt;
                                count_invest++;
                    }

                    //print out final balance for selection 3
                    for (user_selection = 3; user_selection<=3; user_selection++)
                    {
                                printf("The final balance is $%.2f.", balance_of_fund);
                                printf("There were %d donations and %d investments.",count_donate,count_invest);
                    }
        }
   //Quit for selection 4
        else if (user_selection == 4)
        {
                printf("The final balance is $%.2f.",balance_of_fund);
        }
        else
        {
                    printf("Please make a valid selection");
        }
        return 0;
```

}

Comment: I agree, however they are expecting me to use for-loops for this assignment

Comment: check the answer again I have edited and next time you post any question make sure you include errors too.